# Missing GRUB files, cant enter Windows!

Tags: grub2, windows

So i was uppdating Windows, and it restarted itself. When it booted itself up again, it had entered Grub rescue mode. This is what i get:

error: ’file /boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod’ not found
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>

It doesnt recognize any commands at all. I have tried to reinstall Windows using a USB thingy, although it just asks me to pull out the USB, but when i do that, it just boots into Ubuntu again.

All im asking for, is a way to either uninstall Ubuntu completely, since im not using it, or a way to install GRUB, so that i can open Windows again.

Im a total beginner to Linux/Ubuntu, so please, use simple language :)

Comment: Try booting Ubuntu (because you said you can) and run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Ok, i cannot boot into Ubuntu directly, altough i can get inte the ”try” version. Will It work?

Comment: That would be a live session, booting from external media. If you want help you better start describing the issues assertively. And if you want Windows only, what exactly is stopping you from booting Windows installation media and repair it or reinstall? Honestly, your question has no place here and I suggest you learn the basics before installing OSes, any OS.

Answer (score 0):

To boot into the Ubuntu try doing these steps:

- You will first of all need to find the partition Ubuntu is installed. To do that enter `ls` in grub rescue to list all partitons, and then the command `ls (hdx,y)` where 'x' is the drive letter and 'y' is the partiton number. Do that for each partition until you find a partition which is recognized, that partition is probably the one Ubuntu is installed on.
- Once you found the partition you believe Ubuntu is installed on, enter these commands (in grub rescue):

  `set prefix=[the Ubuntu drive]/boot/grub`

  `insmod normal`

  `normal`

It should now forward you to the grub menu. From there boot you boot into Ubuntu and try doing what MichaelBay suggested - `sudo update-grub` in the terminal.

Good luck